# Get the highest number from an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array:

```
Array ( [0] => 80 ) Array ( [0] => 20 ) Array ( [0] => 90 )
```

Code:

```
    $percentage_query        = $this->Common_model->getTableData('prop_payment_percentage', array('list_id' => $id));

    $percentage_result = $percentage_query->result_array();

        foreach ($percentage_result as $ptime) {

            $percentage_start_date = $percentage_query->row()->start_date;
            $percentage_end_date = $percentage_query->row()->end_date;
            $percentage_percentage = $percentage_query->row()->percentage;

            //Days between start date and end date -> seasonal price
            $start_time = $ptime['start_date'];
            $end_time = $ptime['end_date'];
            $hightest_percentage = $ptime['percentage']; // this is the array 802090

            //help me echo 90
        }
```

How should i return the Value 90? As It is the highest number which i would like to return into a $variable

Comment: 1. You have three seperate Arrays. 2. Open Google -> type "highest value of array php"

Comment: the reason i posted the question is because they are 3 seperated

Comment: Give a little context (code), otherwise it's impossible to help you. Are the arrays stored inside an array? are there 3 variables $arr1, $arr2 and $arr3? what do you want do do?

Comment: @IlanHasanov: how are these stored? In three separate variables, or within another array?

Comment: @MichaelKunst I have added how i get those arrays.

Comment: You can loop through each array. Lets say you have a variable called maxNumber = 0; Then check each iteration to see if your array value is greater than maxNumber....If so thats your new maxNumber.

Comment: you're code can't possibly give you those arrays. you don't have any `/` in you're `hightest_percentage`, so an explode won't give you these values. If you have you're arrays stored in a master array look at my answer, otherwise be clearer in with you're question.

Comment: This way, `print_r($hpr);` will print `Array ( [0] => 802090 )`

Comment: @MartenKoetsier Well i have the series of array. I can't go deep why $hpr prints me this kind or arrays i just need the highest value from them.

Comment: @IlanHasanov: then my solution should work. `max` takes arrays of arrays as well (see also my updated answer).

Comment: @MartenKoetsier if i do max on $hpr i get back 802090

Comment: @IlanHasanov: looking at the code you provided: of course it will. Have you tried the `print_r` line? Line 1 will assign (integer) 802090. Line 2 will split this by `'/'` (which it does not contain) into the string `"802090"`. Line 3 will just echo that, not the array you provide in the top of the question.

Comment: @IlanHasanov: can you elaborate more on how you got the value of `$hightest_percentage`? (If it _is_ this integer value, the explode function will not return what you expect!)

Comment: @MartenKoetsier i know a normal explode would not return this but it does. posted the whole code.

Comment: Is the `explode` function overwritten somewhere else in your code?

Comment: It is still not clear what you are working from. You mention an "array 802090", but "802090" is an integer, not an array. Could you update the question by posting the output of `var_dump($hightest_percentage);` (just after the `$hightest_percentage = $ptime['percentage'];` line) in your question?

Comment: What does `$ptime['percentage'];` contain **EXACTLY**?

Comment: @MichaelKunst EXACTLY it contains : 802090. just this number

Comment: Not possible. if you execute `print_r(explode('/', 802090));` it will give you, as many have pointed out, `Array ( [0] => 802090 )`. Maybe you could add you're query aswell as the datatype of `percentage` in your db

Comment: @MichaelKunst I try to explain that the code is not pure. and i have to work with the output i have

Comment: what does `var_dump($ptime['percentage']);` say?

Comment: @MichaelKunst string(2) "80" string(2) "20" string(2) "90"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88593/discussion-between-michael-kunst-and-ilan-hasanov).

Comment: if `var_dump($ptime['percentage']);` gives you those strings, then `echo max($ptime['percentage']);` will print `90`...

Answer (score 1):

Unless the array is sorted, that's the best you're going to get. If it is sorted, just take the first and last elements.

Of course, if it's not sorted, then sorting first and grabbing the first and last is guaranteed to be less efficient than just looping through once. Even the best sorting algorithms have to look at each element more than once (an average of O(log N) times for each element. That's O(N*Log N) total. A simple scan once through is only O(N).

If you are wanting quick access to the largest element in a data structure, take a look at heaps for an efficient way to keep objects in some sort of order.

```
sort() - sort arrays in ascending order
rsort() - sort arrays in descending order
asort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the value
ksort() - sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the key
arsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the value
krsort() - sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the key
```

if we use ascending order then to access last element we have to count array size and arr[last_position] gives highest order

But by sorting array in descending order there is no need to count array size. Just access first number and you will get highest number

Answer (score 0):

if you have an array containing your arrays, you can do it like this:

```
$masterArray = array(
  array(80),
  array(20),
  array(90),
);
$highestValue = 0;
foreach($masterArray as $arr){
  $highestValue = $arr[0] > $highestValue ? $arr[0] : $highestValue;
}
echo $highestValue; //echo 90;
```

Comment: output it gave me is 829 the first letter of each value. what did i miss?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example If you have 3 array or variables.

```
$a1 = Array ( "0" => 80 );
$a2 = Array ( "0" => 20 );
$a3 = Array ( "0" => 90 );

$a4 = array_merge($a1,$a2);

$a5 = array_merge($a4,$a3);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(max($a5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop. Merge the three arrays and then use max();

```
    $array = array_merge(array(80),array(20),array(20));
    $max = max($array);
```

Comment: merging is not even necessary, `max` takes all comparable variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$a=array(0 => 1300 );
$b=array(0 => 500 );
$c=array(0 => 1220 );

$MaxValue=0;

if($a[0]>$b[0])
{
        $MaxValue=$a[0];
    if($b[0]>$MaxValue)
    {
        $MaxValue=$b[0];
    }
    else
    {
        if($c[0]>$MaxValue)
        {$MaxValue=$c[0];}
    }
}
else
{
    if($b[0]>$c[0])
    {
        $MaxValue=$b[0];
    }
    else
    {
        $MaxValue=$c[0];
    }
}
echo $MaxValue;
?>
```

Comment: outputs 829.. the first letter of each number

Comment: No @IlanHasanov. Working Fine For Me. Your array is this.. 

$array = array(0 => 80, 1 => 20, 2 => 90); Displaying 90 for me

Comment: my array are three arrays Array ( [0] => 80 ) Array ( [0] => 20 ) Array ( [0] => 90 )

Comment: just copy my code.. and run in separate page.. to get the result.. @IlanHasanov. Working fine.

Comment: Although this solution should work, using `echo max($array);` will be a lot less code and it might even be faster because it is a native core function... Also less error-prone...

Comment: @MartenKoetsier thanks for helping out but max doesn't help here at all. i need to join those arrays into one

Comment: @DanishEnam the arrays are not seperated by variables. they are inside a one variable

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way would be to use the standard code function from php:

```
$array = array(0 => 80, 1 => 20, 2 => 90);
$variable = max($array);
```

See also the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

**update:** this function takes more than just an array of integers. All these are valid and return `3` as expected:

```
$a1 = array(1);
$a2 = array(2);
$a3 = array(3);

$i1 = 1;
$i2 = 2;
$i3 = 3;

$arr1 = array($a1, $a2, $a3);
$arr2 = array($i1, $i2, $i3);

echo max($a1, $a2, $a3), "\n";  // 3
echo max($i1, $i2, $i3), "\n";  // 3
echo max($arr1), "\n";  // 3
echo max($arr2), "\n";  // 3
```

It does not matter what keys are used in the arrays.

**update 2:** if you really need to work from the value `802090` and you can be sure that the values are always 2-digit percentages, you could also use the `str_split` function (and then again the `max` function):

```
$hightest_percentage = 802090;
$hpr = str_split($hightest_percentage, 2);  // array ( 80, 20, 90 );
print_r(max($hpr)); // 90
```

Comment: as you can see they come as 3 seperate arrays with [0] as the key

Comment: are those separate arrays in separate variables, or in a "super" array?

Comment: those 3 arrays are coming from an Explode function

Comment: That still does not answer the question of how they are stored. If the three arrays are stored within one big array (array of arrays), you can use the `max` function as suggested. If they are three separate variables, you may also use the `max` function, but with more parameters.